# Function to sort one-dimensional array doesnt work?

Tags: c, arrays

I need to make a function that sorts one-dimensional array in such way that, numbers smaller than first element are moved before it and numbers bigger or equal, are moved after. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void sort(int a[], int n);

int main(){
    int a[10], i, m;
    do{
        printf("Enter number of elements: ");
        scanf("%d", &m);
    } while (m < 1 || m > 10);

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        sort(a, m);

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);

    return 0;
}

void sort(int a[], int m){
    int i, j, p, temp;
    p = a[1];

    for (j = 2; j < m; j++){
        if (p >= a[j]){
            temp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[1];
            a[1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you know that in C that an array of size 10 is indexed from 0 to 9?

Comment: yes, but even 1-10 still works, and its just easier for me that way, I can change it after.

Comment: No, it doesn't work, otherwise you wouldn't be here.  Accessing out of the bounds of an array is undefined behavior.

Comment: Ok I've fixed it and it still doesnt order them as needed.

Comment: Please explain in English (not code) how your sort function works.  Then figure out if that works (it doesn't).  Then only after getting the algorithm written down on paper should you write the code.

Comment: Have you tried starting with hard-coded values and getting those to sort before trying to get user input?

Comment: @JustSteve if you try and access the last element of the array `a` as `a[10]` you will get undefined behavior. Also, you will need to have two nested loops or something similar to get your `sort` code to work. Look for a `bubble sort` implementation to borrow.  Then only call sort once, instead of calling it multiple times.

Comment: I don't see how this code is supposed to sort anything. It looks like you have heard something about bubble sort, but very briefly.

Comment: @EugeneSh. -- OP isn't actually "sorting" ... looks like from the description OP is trying to "partition" based on a pivot of the first element and is just using wrong terminology.

Comment: Check out the [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Algorithm) function of quicksort.  I think this is what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sorting function is the issue. work through the logic on paper and you'll see what is going on. Your p is fixed in place which is part of the problem. You'll notice that yours is moving the inputs around, it's just a matter of how it is moving them

This sorting function should work if you drop it in place.

```
void sort(int a[], int m){
int i, j, p, temp;

for (i =0; i<m;i++){
    for(j=i;j<m;j++){
        if (a[j]<a[i]){
            temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit, Oh, I may have misinterpreted your question. Is that to say that you do not want them to be in completely perfect order but rather that you want things smaller than the starting element to be in front of it but in the same order that they were in when entered?

Edit 2:
Sorry I misunderstood your previous question. Here is what I came up with.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void sort(int a[], int n);

int main(){
    int a[10], i, m;
    do{
        printf("Enter number of elements: ");
        scanf("%d", &m);
    } while (m < 1 || m > 10);

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);

    sort(a, m);

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);

    return 0;
}

void sort(int a[], int m){
    int i, j, p, temp; 
    int pindex;

    p = a[0];
    pindex =0;

    for (i =0; i<m;i++){
        if(a[i]<p){
            temp = a[i];
            for(j=i;j>pindex;j--){
               a[j] = a[j-1];
            }
            a[pindex]=temp;
            pindex++;
        }
    }

}
```

I think that the biggest issue with your initial approach was the fact that you were setting p to the first element every single time the loop ran. If p changes with each iteration it ends up breaking everything.

The changes I made: I track the current location of p with a variable called pindex. Whenever I find an element less than p I slide every element back until I get to p (including p). Then I place the element that I found in the index where p was.

Hope that is helpful.

Comment: He couldn't drop it in place since he's calling sort `m` times

Comment: Oh, that is true. I guess I need to pay closer attention.

Comment: @JustSteve If the edit is ***exactly*** what you're trying to do, then you need to [edit] your question to make that clear. Because the question doesn't say anything about keeping the smaller elements in the ***same*** order.